# Chamar funcao de outro controller no angular

Tags: angularjs

Tenho este `controller`:

```
myApp.controller('listarClientesController', function($scope, $http){

$scope.lista = listarClientes();

function listarClientes() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '/index.php/Clientes/Listar'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.clientes = response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        toastr["error"]("Erro ao obter os registros", "Sistema");
    });
}});
```

Preciso chamar `listarClientes` depois que inseri com sucesso neste `controller`:

```
myApp.controller('cadastrarClienteController', function($scope, $http)

  $scope.cadastrarCliente = function () {

  $scope.cliente = {
    CliNome: $scope.cliente.CliNome,
    CliTelefone: $scope.cliente.CliTelefone,
    CliEmail: $scope.cliente.CliEmail,
    CliDescricao: $scope.cliente.CliDescricao
   };

var response = $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "/index.php/Clientes/create",
    data: $scope.cliente,
    dataType: "json"
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    toastr["success"]("Registro inserido com sucesso!", "Sistema");
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    toastr["error"]("Erro ao inserir o registro", "Sistema");
});

$scope.lista;

return response;
```

Edit:

Service:

```
myApp.service('clienteService', function($scope, $http){

this.listarClientes = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '/index.php/Clientes/Listar'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.clientes = response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        toastr["error"]("Erro ao obter os registros", "Sistema");
    });
}});
```

Edit:

assim declaro no controller:

```
myApp.controller('cadastrarClienteController', function($scope, $http, clienteService){
```

Conserto:

```
myApp.service('clienteService', function($http){
this.ListarClientes = function() {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + '/index.php/Clientes/Listar');
}
```

});

Obrigado!

Comment: Já pesquisou a ideia de "factories" e "services" do AngularJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está consumindo a mesma fonte de dados a partir de vários lugares na sua aplicação talvez valha a pena implementar sua fonte como um serviço ou *factory*, como indicado no comentário do [Gabriel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/38695/gabriel-katakura):

```
.factory(
    "clientesFactory", function ($resource) {
        return $resource("/index.php/Clientes/Listar");
    })
```

E consuma este *factory* onde precisar:

```
myApp.controller('listarClientesController', function($scope, clientesFactory){
    clientesFactory.query(function(data){ $scope.lista = data; });
}
```

Comment: Ok... coloquei a função que preciso num service... editei minha pergunta... está dando erro no service.. é do jeito que fiz?

Comment: @novato poderia descrever o erro?

Comment: ` $scopeProvider <- $scope <- clienteService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20clienteService`